# USB stick (pen drive) w/ Type-C connector & USB 3.1 speed

Tags: usb, data-storage, flash-drive

I'm looking for a high speed pen drive (not sure about terminology - USB stick?) with USB Type C connector and at least USB 3.1 Gen1 speed.

I have found a SanDisk one but it says up to 130MB/s transfer speed and 3.1 speed while the SanDisk Extreme Pro with Type A connector and 3.0 speed says up to 430MB/s transfer speed.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a budget for this flash drive? How much storage are you looking for?

Comment: I have seen all sort of prices so let’s say I don’t have a budget but care only about performance. I would like to use it as an external bootable drive with macOS High Sierra. If partitioning it would work I would accept any size, otherwise 16GB. Thanks

Comment: No suggestion?? Does anyone have experience with USB-C pen drives? Have you tried some? Thanks